# Summa equation to solve

Tags: summation

I'm having an hard time inverting this formula in order to get $x$. 
This is a short form for the amount of Energy deposited in a single pixel of a detector.

$$ K = \sum_E f(E) e^{-(g(E) \cdot x)} $$

Where $f(E)$ and $g(E)$ are two functions summed over $E$, $K$ is a constant. $x$ doesn't depend on $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You can't invert a linear combination of exponentials analytically. Only numerically. Even with just two terms.

For instance,

$$y=e^x+e^{5x}$$ amounts to a non-solvable quintic.

Comment: Ok so it wasn't me forgetting some trivial math. Thank you.